String.Join on stack, joining for the end of stack?
I have a stack [element1, element2]. My desired result is: element1/element2

My code:  String.Join("/", stack);
My result: element2/element1 instead of element1/element2.

Any ideas?

Is String.Join("/", stack.Reverse()) what you want?

@dbc indeed that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Perhaps you wanted a Queue instead of a Stack?

A stack is a LIFO data structure, so when you iterate over it (e.g., with String.Join), the elements are accessed in reverse order of insertion.
so If you want the elements in the order they were added you need to reverse the stack before joining. Like..
String.Join("/", stack.Reverse());

